# calculating the overall importance. Angularjs

Tags: javascript, algorithm, angularjs

Consider the example: http://jsfiddle.net/KWLu7/16/

I'm trying to calculate *overall importance* value as *sum* of *each selected choice importance* multiplied on its *parent criterion importance*:

```
var watch = $scope.$watch("prioritizationProfile", function() {
    $scope.overallImportance = 0;

    for(var j = 0; j < $scope.prioritizationProfile.length; j++) {
        var criterionGroup = $scope.prioritizationProfile[j].criterionGroup;

        for(var i = 0; i < criterionGroup.length; i++) {

            var criterionChoices = criterionGroup[i].choices;

            for(var k = 0; k < criterionChoices.length; k++) {
                console.log(criterionChoices[k]);
                if(criterionChoices[k].selected) {
                    $scope.overallImportance += 
                        criterionChoices[i].importance * 
                        criterionGroup[i].importance;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}, true);
```

If you try it you will see that maximal value is always 22. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong index in your inner for loop of `prioritizationProfileWatch`

Change

```
$scope.overallImportance += criterionChoices[i].importance * criterionGroup[i].importance;
```

To

```
$scope.overallImportance += criterionChoices[k].importance * criterionGroup[i].importance;
```